# PHP problem with "__php_incomplete_class"

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, object

I'm developing a website with CodeIgniter and have created a User and a session:

```
$user->first_name = 'Gerep';
$user->gender = 'M';
$user->age = '26';


$this->session->set_userdata('user', $user);
```

But when I try to access the session object:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('user')->first_name;
```

It returns me a error: `Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string`

I have always worked like that and never had that problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class definition had not been loaded, when PHP tried to deserialize the object in the session.

You can solve your problem by employing [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: the session is been autoloaded on the autoload.php file, isn't that enogh?

Comment: I don't know what your script does. But what I do know is this: If you put an object into $_SESSION, PHP will serialize it to store it, and unserialize it when you access it again. If the class has not yet been parsed/loaded by PHP, you will get such an error. I suggest you check which object exactly is the culprit. If you `var_dump()` the object, you can see `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` on the problematic object.

Comment: Yeah...with var_dump I see the object as it needs to be but the type is __PHP_Incomplete_Class. I'm gonna check my classes again...

Answer (score 2):

The solution works, but you need to ensure that the class object definitions are read before session:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('**our class**','session','form_validation');
```

Comment: Models cant load in libraries array

Answer (score 1):

The position of session_start() is important becouse script loaded from top to bothom. When you call it before spl_autoload session is loaded before cllass(Object) and does not know where to put data, so it's been created __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object.
Before:

```
 session_start();

 spl_autoload_register(function($class){
     require_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
 });
```

Result: __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object ( [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => User [id]...)
After:

```
 spl_autoload_register(function($class){
 require_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
 });

 session_start();
```

Result: User Object ( [id] =>...)

Answer (score 0):

Look if you had any __autoload($class) and change it to use the spl_autoload_register() way. Example:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'core/' . $class  .EXT)) {
        require_once APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT;
    } else {
        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT)) {
            require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT;
        }
    }
}
```

would be changed to:

```
function CIautoload($class)
{
    if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'core/' . $class  .EXT)) {
        require_once APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT;
    } else {
        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT)) {
            require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT;
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('CIautoload');
```

This way, you'll be able of using all the PHP 5.3 power (and you won't have problem with composer autoloads and CI, ;D)

### Explanation

If after a while using PHP 5.2 you start to use PHP > 5.3 and all the OO way of coding, you will start to use `spl_autoload_register`. With CI, in projects with PHP 5.2, as you couldn't use `spl_autoload_register` people used a known hack to autolad classes using a `function __autoload($class)` that they usually wrote on the config.php file. 
Problem is when you mix both, the `spl_autoload_register` function will override your `__autoload` class and the error the question ask for will arise.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me recently, and reading the solutions give me an idea. The first problem is that the `session_start` was before than the `autload`, that's the error. You must declare your `autload` or include this then you can do the `session_start`.

Comment: I don't see how the placement of the session_start would cause the error he is reporting. Can you explain further?