# EOAuthUserIdentity getting error on getting token

Tags: php, yii, oauth

I am using [jorgebg/yii-eoauth](https://github.com/jorgebg/yii-eoauth) library. I use the library with [Yii EAuth extension](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth/). [By requirements `yii eauth`](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth/#requirements)

Requirements

- Yii 1.1 or above
- PHP curl extension
- loid extension
- **EOAuth extension**

Well, I come across with [this problem](https://github.com/jorgebg/yii-eoauth/issues/6). I checked it in local with linkedin account (no social accounts work on local server, except linkedin ) and it works perfectly. But login system doesn't work on server. Can you help me in this case ? Thanks in advance !

I didn't write my code here, because I thought, the problem doesn't depend on my code. If it is not, I can put here necessary code.

**EDIT:**

Error was :

```
Argument 1 passed to EOAuthUtils::GetAccessToken() must be an instance of
 OAuthConsumer, instance of __PHP_Incomplete_Class given, called in 
protected/extensions/eoauth/EOAuthUserIdentity.php on line 138 and defined
```

In line 138 of EOAuthUserIdentity.php was written:

```
// Upgrade to access token.
$token = EOAuthUtils::GetAccessToken($consumer, $token, $oauthVerifier,
                    $this->provider->access_token_endpoint);
```

I put logger `pre($consumer,1);` before above code. and I had in local:

```
OAuthConsumer Object
(
    [key] => 7........k
    [secret] => s........r
    [callback_url] => 
)
```

I had on server:

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => OAuthConsumer
    [key] => 7.........k
    [secret] => s........r
    [callback_url] => 
)
```

the same `php` version on local and server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need load class before unserialize object. If u don't do this, object unserialize to __PHP_Incomplete_Class.

see [PHP problem with "__php_incomplete_class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574984/php-problem-with-php-incomplete-class)